# Call CI Controller from ExtJs

Tags: extjs, codeigniter-2, extjs4.2

I am creating `controller` in `Code Igniter` and make `form` in `ExtJs 4.2.1` now from where i call control and how?
i used `url` property of `form` and put `controller` name there but nothing happen

**Update**

I think i am not clearing my question actually i want to post data through `submit` function in which i pass data to php file in my server side i use `Code Igniter Rest Api` so here i want pass data to specific controller

Answer (score 0):

ExtJs is a javascript framework and is executed on the client side. It has its own MCV system.

It makes no sense to mix up a php controller with a javascript view.

Be sure to read the [introduction to MVC in ExtJS](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/application_architecture).

Also in ExtJS you don't call the controller. On initialisation of the app, all controllers get lloaded. In the controller you define what it has to control, and from then on the magic hhappens: The events defined in the controller are fired whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJS 3.3.1

In login form put the buttons and call function submit_login();

```
buttons: [{
        text: 'Login',
        handler: function() {
            submit_login();
        }
    }]
```

Submit_login() code is, I used Ext.Ajax.request to submit login parameters
You can debug the message with alert(response.responseText):

```
function submit_login() {var useridx = Ext.getCmp('useridx').getValue();var userpasswordx = Ext.getCmp('userpasswordx').getValue();Ext.Ajax.request({url:'".$url."',        method:'POST',
    params :{useridx:useridx,userpasswordx:userpasswordx},
    success:function(response){
        //alert(response.responseText);
        //return;
        var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
        var resultMessage = jsonData.Message;
        var isLogin = jsonData.isLogin;
        if (isLogin)
        {
            window.location = '';
        }
        else
        {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Info',resultMessage);
        }
    },
    failure: function(){
    Ext.Msg.alert('Not OK');
    }
});
```

}

variable $url is:

```
$url = "index.php/apps/login";
```

You can create Apps controller
and create function login

```
public function login()
{
    $this->load->view('login');
}
```

Create login.php in view

```
        if ($i==1) {
        //session_start();
        $this->session->set_userdata('userid',$useridx); echo '{"success" : true, "isLogin": true,"Message" : "User Successfully Login"}';
    } else {

        echo '{"success" : true, "isLogin": false, "Message" : "Salah User: '.$useridx.' dan Password "}';
    }
```

You also do this in Ext JS 4.2.1 with same code.

This is works for me

Andrex Maulana